# How do you play an external .mov file in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3

[How do I load a MOV file into Flash 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840213/how-do-i-load-a-mov-file-into-flash-9)

I checked this post out and it looks like the normal way for adding a flv, but it tried it on some sample .movs from apple and doesnt seem to work.

Do movs have to be encoded specially for playback in flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.mov files encoded in h.264 work in flash, although i wasn't happy with the playback performance on my mac.